# Scala - replaceAllIn

Tags: regex, scala

First off, I'm new to Scala.

I'm trying to make a template parser in Scala (similar to Smarty (PHP)). It needs to search through the document, replacing anything inside "{{ }}" tags, with anything provided in the HashMap.

I'm currently stuck here:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import scala.io.Source

class Template(filename: String, vars: HashMap[Symbol, Any]) {
  def parse() = { 
    var contents = Source.fromFile(filename, "ASCII").mkString
    var rule = """\{\{(.*)\}\}""".r

    //for(rule(v) <- rule findAllIn contents) {
    //  yield v
    //}

    //rule.replaceAllIn(contents, )
  }
}

var t = new Template("FILENAME", new HashMap[Symbol, Any])
println(t.parse)
```

The part's that I've commented are things that I've thought about doing.

Thanks

---

I've come a little further...

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import scala.io.Source
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import java.util.regex.Matcher

class Template(filename: String, vars: HashMap[Symbol, Any]) {

  def findAndReplace(m: Matcher)(callback: String => String):String = {
    val sb = new StringBuffer
    while (m.find) { 
      m.appendReplacement(sb, callback(m.group(1))) 
    }
    m.appendTail(sb)
    sb.toString
  }

  def parse() = { 
    var contents = Source.fromFile(filename, "ASCII").mkString
    val m = Pattern.compile("""\{\{(.*)\}\}""").matcher(contents)

    findAndReplace(m){ x => x }

  }
}

var t = new Template("FILENAME.html", new HashMap[Symbol, Any])
println(t.parse)
```

At the moment it just currently adds whatever was inside of the tag, back into the document. I'm wondering if there is an easier way of doing a find-and-replace style regexp in Scala?

Comment: I'm sorry--what's your question?

Comment: In the document, there will be variables surrounded by "{{" and "}}" e.g. "{{ name }}". I need to find the best way to swap each instance of "{{ WHATEVER }}" with a value inside the hashmap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it like this (String as key instead of Symbol):

```
var s : String = input // line, whatever
val regexp = """pattern""".r

while(regexp findFirstIn s != None) {
  s = regexp replaceFirstIn (s, vars(regexp.findFirstIn(s).get))
}
```

If you prefer not using var, go recursive instead of using while. And, of course, a stringbuilder would be more efficient. In that case, I might do the following:

```
val regexp = """^(.*?)(?:{{(pattern)}})?""".r
for(subs <- regexp findAllIn s)
  subs match {
    case regexp(prefix, var) => sb.append(prefix); if (var != null) sb.append("{{"+vars(var)+"}}")
    case _ => error("Shouldn't happen")
  }
```

That way you keep appending the non-changing part, followed by the next part to be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

There is a flavor of `replaceAllIn` in `util.matching.Regex` that accepts a `replacer` callback. A short example:

```
import util.matching.Regex
def replaceVars(r: Regex)(getVar: String => String) = {
  def replacement(m: Regex.Match) = {
    import java.util.regex.Matcher
    require(m.groupCount == 1)
    Matcher.quoteReplacement( getVar(m group 1) )
  }
  (s: String) => r.replaceAllIn(s, replacement _)
}
```

This is how we would use it:

```
val r = """\{\{([^{}]+)\}\}""".r
val m = Map("FILENAME" -> "aaa.txt",
            "ENCODING" -> "UTF-8")
val template = replaceVars(r)( m.withDefaultValue("UNKNOWN") )

println( template("""whatever input contains {{FILENAME}} and
unknown key {{NOVAL}} and {{FILENAME}} again,
and {{ENCODING}}""") )
```

---

> **Note** `Matcher.quoteReplacement` escapes `$` characters in the replacement string. Otherwise you may get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference, replaceAll and dollar signs`. See [the blog post](http://cephas.net/blog/2006/02/09/javalangillegalargumentexception-illegal-group-reference-replaceall-and-dollar-signs/) on why this may happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here is also interesting way how to do the same using functions compose:

```
  val Regexp = """\{\{([^{}]+)\}\}""".r

  val map = Map("VARIABLE1" -> "VALUE1", "VARIABLE2" -> "VALUE2", "VARIABLE3" -> "VALUE3")

  val incomingData = "I'm {{VARIABLE1}}. I'm {{VARIABLE2}}. And I'm {{VARIABLE3}}. And also {{VARIABLE1}}"


  def replace(incoming: String) = {
    def replace(what: String, `with`: String)(where: String) = where.replace(what, `with`)
    val composedReplace = Regexp.findAllMatchIn(incoming).map { m => replace(m.matched, map(m.group(1)))(_) }.reduceLeftOption((lf, rf) => lf compose rf).getOrElse(identity[String](_))
    composedReplace(incomingData)
  }

  println(replace(incomingData))

  //OUTPUT: I'm VALUE1. I'm VALUE2. And I'm VALUE3. And also VALUE1
```